# Как реализовать поиск в postgresql с Sequelize, в котором будет поиск в ячейке по словам в различном порядке?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

На бэк прилетает `variants = ['one', 'two']`, по содержимому которой мы должны сделать выборку.

Есть таблица PostgreSQL

```
id | name | variants
0 | foo | one
1 | bar | two one
2 | foobar | one two
```

Нужно найти такие строки, в которых будет и 'one' и 'two', не зависимо от порядка.

Пример `variants = ['one', 'two'] -> 1,2`

Пример `variants = ['two', 'one'] -> 1,2`

Пример `variants = ['one'] -> 0,1,2`

Пример `variants = ['two'] -> 1,2`

Я пробовал

```
model = await Item.findAndCountAll({
                    where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('regexp_split_to_array', sequelize.fn('lower', sequelize.col('variants')), '\\s+'),
                        '@>',
                        variants)})
```

Но это почему-то не работает от слова совсем

Comment: *Есть таблица PostgreSQL* Покажите таблицу в виде CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Из текущего отображения мало что можно понять. Также сформулируйте правило формирования списка токенов - например "строго 1 пробел между токенами, начальных и конечных пробелов нет". Но вообще - нормализовали бы Вы эту таблицу... *Нужно найти такие строки, в которых будет и 'one' и 'two'* Да в общем обычное реляционное деление. *не зависимо от порядка* А что, в каких-то случаях порядок токенов в поле `variants` - важен?

Comment: @Akina в этом и фокус, что мне нужен поиск в поле по "тегам", грубо говоря. Для поиска в поле точно до символа мы используем `{where: {name: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('LOWER', sequelize.col('variants')), 'LIKE', '%' + query + '%')}}`, а для поиска "по словам" (+ независимо от порядка этих слов!!!) неизвестно что делать, документацию пролистал, примеров таких запросов нет

Comment: Вы не ту документацию листали. Надо изучать (не только листать!) документацию по нормальным формам - то есть теоретические основы разработки баз данных. Вся проблема - именно от кривой структуры, на которой приходится извращаться, чтобы получить нужный результат. Тогда как на правильно спроектированной структуре это вообще проходная задача, на которой негде напрягаться.

Comment: @Akina ну вот смотрите: у меня есть товар и у него есть вариации(вариаций может быть бесконечное количество), к этим вариациям мне нужно привязать сортировку, то есть условно есть сапоги красные высокие (вариация красный и вариация высокий) и есть сапоги красные низкие. При выборе красный - возвращаем и низкие и высокие, так как вариация "красный" и там и там. ну вы меня поняли, это можно обозвать "тегами", наверное. Я это реализовал так: при создании товара мы  берем массив вариаций и с помощью join(' ') получаем строку, записываем ее в поле бд, но получить желаемое по этим "тегам" - не могу.

Comment: @Akina Я дилетант в беке, но задача стоит и ее решить надо, может посоветуете как-то переорганизовать саму бд ? Нет идей как сделать такое иначе

Comment: `при создании товара мы берем массив вариаций и с помощью join(' ') получаем строку` не делайте строчку, а кладите характеристики в массив text[]. тогда поиск можно будет сделать так `variants @> ['красный', 'низкий']::text[]` или `variants && ['красный', 'низкий']::text[]`. но нужно задуматься вот над чем: что вы будете делать, если наименование характеристики изменится, допустим с "красный" на "red"...